# Generic Subprogram taking type from a package implementing Ada.Iterator_Interfaces to take advantage of Ada 2012 for .. in/of loop syntax

Tags: generics, ada, ada2012

As I understand from [here](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-128-iterators-in-ada-2012-part-2) anything that implements Ada.Iterator_Interfaces can use the Ada 2012 for loop syntax. "for ... [in|of] .. loop .. end loop;

How do I create a generic subprogram that I can instantiate with a type in a package that implements the Ada.Iterator_Interfaces? and so then be able to have that subprogram iterate over that type using an Ada 2012 for loop.

In Java this might look like:

```
public String join(Iterable<String> collection) {
   for (item : collection){
     //do stuff
   } 
}
```

For example (although not the only case) a classic join function that can take any iterable container containing strings and return all the strings joined together in a string list.
eg.

```
my_container = ["a","b","c"]
join(my_container) = "abc"
```

Thanks

Matt

Comment: so... what's your question?

Comment: Are you looking for [generic formal derived types](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-5-1.html)?  They work with interfaces too.  `generic type T is new Ada.Iterator_Interfaces with private;...` and now your instantiation requires a type that implements `Iterator_Interfaces`.

Comment: thanks , yes close to that - I've added a java example to be more clear.